# MySQL : Table 'my_table' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql

If i try

```
select * from my_table
```

i get:

```
"Table 'my_table' doesn't exist in engine"
```

but

```
show tables
```

contains this table in list.

I tried:

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --check --all-databases
```

but also get

```
Table 'my_table' doesn't exist in engine
```

Mysql version:

```
Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.11-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

I checked /var/lib/mysql/mydatabase - *.frm and *.ibd for certain tables exist

Comment: Are you using the correct Schema/Database?

Comment: Yes, sure. I did same things before. I was ok.

Comment: Looks like table body file was deleted. Check it in the filesystem.

Comment: Akina , files are exist in /var/lib/mysq/mydatabase/